# Binding to "global" ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I would like to have a an object that is seen from multiple views.
Each view has a Viewmodel.

Is it possible to have a "global" viewmodel with and object that I cand binding from all views of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.  This is often done in the "ViewModelLocator" pattern - google will point you towards tons of examples but here's a good one to start with:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170222162805/http://www.terrymarshall.com.au/Blog/tabid/162/EntryId/117/Windows-8-and-MVVM-Part-3-ViewModelLocator.aspx

Comment: Thank tou @robert I've been looking for but it could find anything. Can you show me an example of how to do the thing that I said in my question please?

Comment: the link i provided has an example

Comment: An example of viewmodellocator but I could understand how it is related with a "global" viewmodel, something like a singleton..

Comment: the viewmodellocator is a global object that is added to Application.Resources so it can be referenced in bindings